# Submitting custom request marshallers to JAXRSClientFactory

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I am trying to invoke my RESTful service using JAXRSClientFactory - and I'm stuck with supplying configuration for request/response mappings types (I need to serialize List)

The code looks like this:

```
JAXRSClientFactory.create("http://localhost:8080/", MyCoolService.class, "/path/to/client/config.xml");
```

the config.xml looks like:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
       http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        ">

    <jaxrs:client id="testClient" createdFromAPI="true">
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="my.provider.Class"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:client>

</beans>
```

now when debugging client code, I can see that within org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory there is the call

```
    MessageBodyWriter<T> mw = chooseMessageWriter(messageWriters, 
                                                  bodyType,
                                                  parameterType,
                                                  parameterAnnotations,
                                                  mediaType,
                                                  m);
```

however **messageWriters** doesn't contain my provider. What is wrong with my code and how to provide MessageBodyWriter correctly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically the problem was related to **createdFromAPI="true"**

So I got rid of the XML file and used specialized version of JAXRSClientFactory, which accepts list of message body providers as method parameter

If there is the need to provide basic authentication - then

```
    ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(proxy);
    HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) config.getConduit();
    AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicy();
    authorizationPolicy.setUserName(USERNAME);                     
    authorizationPolicy.setPassword(PASSWORD);                   
    conduit.setAuthorization(authorizationPolicy);
```

Comment: There's now a config.getHttpConduit() method which cleans up that code a tiny bit.