# Getting CXF JAX-RS Client to use Jackson

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, jackson

I can't figure out how to use Jackson with the CXF client for Jax-RS.

I've seen some references claiming I should be adding the following XML snippet, however, I have no idea where I should be adding this.  Is this only relevant when using Services or can I also set this with a client?

```
<jaxrs:providers>
   <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
</jaxrs:providers>
```

The way I'm currently creating my clients is:

`MyServiceClass client = JAXRSClientFactory.create(serverUrl, MyServiceClass.class);`

How do I set this client to use Jackson?  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to see it. . .

```
Thanks!
```

Comment: Is this is what you are looking for: `JAXRSClientFactory.create(serverUrl, MyServiceClass.class, "/path/to/client/config.xml");`?

Comment: Relative: [Submitting custom request marshallers to JAXRSClientFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662060).

Comment: Thanks, @dma_k! For non-Spring users: JAXRSClientFactory.create(serverUrl, MyServiceClass.class, Collections.singletonList(new JacksonJsonProvider()))

Answer (score 1):

This will probably do it: [JAXRSClientFactory#create(String,Class,List)](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/JAXRSClientFactory.html#create(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.util.List))

The list is declared as `List<?>` because you can pass anything in there and it should be handled correctly - assuming it has the correct annotations.